# GBQ | Python: How can I retrieve data types of all the columns in a table?

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I have used the below code to get the list of columns and it works fine.

```
table_ref = dataset_ref.table(table_name)
table = client.get_table(table_ref)
field_names = [field.name for field in table.schema]
```

But when I tried the below code to get the datatypes, I'm getting an error - AttributeError: 'SchemaField' object has no attribute 'type'

```
field_types = [field.type for field in table.schema]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
field_types = [field.field_type for field in table.schema]
```

As it seems the property name is [field_type](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/blob/master/bigquery/google/cloud/bigquery/schema.py#L75) instead of just "type".

Comment: tks, SchemaField.field_type is the property i need